# Android - How to manage Wifi connection to be updated on every change everytime

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, wifi

I'm developing an app with a `WebView` that loads some content from the web.

What I'm trying to do is to detect every Wi-Fi change (connected or not connected) and show a dialog if Wi-Fi is not connected or the content of the `WebView` if it is connected.

I implemented a `BroadcastReceiver` with action `android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED`:

```
public class SyncOfflineDataOnWifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        NetworkInfo info = (NetworkInfo)intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
        if (info!=null && info.getDetailedState() == DetailedState.CONNECTED) {
            Application.setInternet(true);
        }else{
            Application.setInternet(false);
        }
    }
}
```

So when Wi-Fi connects flag `boolean Internet` is set to `true` (otherwise `false`).

What I need is a module that tries to reconnect to the same Wi-Fi (the saved one) till it is not connected. Is possible to have something like this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's possible. It's in the WiFi manager API. Review it, especially the `reassociate()` and `reconnect()` methods: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html

Comment: how can i integrate it with my system?

Comment: That's for you to decide. WiFi manager provides the API you need, rest is your job...